# How to load combo box until current month using VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, load

I have combo box for month that will load all the previous months until the current month. For example current month today is July. So it'll load from January until July using VB.Net.
Here is my combobox in asp.net :

`<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbMonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></dx:ASPxComboBox>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with code instead ask silly questions, here i give sample code which get all months in one list and get current month name also. Loop the month list and check that month is current month or not.

```
    Dim months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames.Take(12).ToList
    Dim iMonth As Integer = Month(System.DateTime.Now)
    Dim GetMonthName As String = MonthName(iMonth)

    For i = 0 To months.Count-1

       
        If months(i) = GetMonthName Then
            GoTo Reachhear
        End If
    Dim aa As String = months(i) ' Here u will add months(i) in Combobox one by one
    Next
```

Reachhear:

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming this drop down list?

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
            DataValueField ="value"
            DataTextField="text"
            AutoPostBack="true" Width="129px" >               
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Then our code to fill above will be this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim CurrentMonth = Month(DateTime.Now)

        For i = 1 To CurrentMonth
            Dim MyItem As New ListItem(MonthName(i), i)
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(MyItem)
        Next
        ' optional please select (quite much required with auto post back = true
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Month", "0"))

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Debug.Print("drop month number = " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
    Debug.Print("drop month as text = " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)

End Sub
```

And the results are this:

[image]

when we select say in above (April), then debug shows this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I use ASPxCombobox but it still work just instead of using ` Dim MyItem As New ListItem(MonthName(i), i)` I use ` Dim myItem As String = months(i)`.